# .net trying to compile config file

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0

I've never seen Visual Studio try to compile a web.config file before. But I'm getting compilation errors on almost every line of the file.

First line consists of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

And I get 7 errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS1031  Type expected   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS1031  Type expected   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Portal  {Path}\Views\Web.config 1   Active
```

Why would it be compiling this file and how do I tell it not to?

Comment: Right click, properties, check what the settings are for the file. Any file can be set to be compiled if so wanted so maybe for some reason this has happened

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the file from the project and re-adding it fixed the problem.
Comparing before and after, the csproj had the file listed as Compile instead of Content.

```
<Content Include="{Path}\Web.config" />
```